# Is there a html/css reader on pages?

Tags: html, css

Is there some sort of software, where I can go on a website and see all the **html** and **css** it consists of?

btw: I want to use it for learning (not to copy - I'm not near trying to create a website yet), and see how people make their websites.

*Thanks*

Comment: Your browser's inspector goes a long way.

Comment: On chrome open the page and press Ctrl+U to see the source code. This question is likely to be closed as it is not about programming.

Comment: All modern browsers have built-in Developer Tools, usually available by pressing F12

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered the Google Chrome inspector? your browser is technically the software you're looking for.

Open Google Chrome -> hit Ctrl + Shift + I -> Go to a website and on the Network tab of Developer Tools you'll see all the site's dependencies such as CSS/JS, etc. You can view or save them directly from there.